# Isomorphism between $\bigwedge^k V$ and $\bigwedge^{n-k} V^*$?

Tags: group-isomorphism, exterior-algebra

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237442/isomorphic-representations-on-exterior-powers) states the existence of an isomorphism between  $\bigwedge^k V$ and $\bigwedge^{n-k} V^*$. I am new to this subject and was wondering how such an isomorphism can be proved?

Comment: Do you want isomorphism as vector spaces? You only need to show they have same dimension, unless you want a canonical isomorphism.

Comment: You omitted a crucial condition in that link: that these are isomorphic as representations over $\text{SL}(V)$ **not** over $\text{GL}(V)$.

Comment: @edm I am talking about vector spaces. I am actually slightly confused about the difference between an isomorphism and a canonical isomorphism. From what I know an isomorphism is the existence of a map that is moth bijective and a homomorphism. Is this correct? what makes a canonical isomorphism different?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification : In simple words, canonical isomorphism is something which does not depend on chosen basis of the vector space. Ok, do you know that for any finite dimensional space $V$ there is an isomorphism $V\rightarrow V^*$. Can you tell me the map?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I do know that they are isomorphic (at least know anyway), and I cannot tell you a map (at least one that is not basis independent). I have read in the past that two groups that are isomorphic can essentially be considered the same. Given that $V $ and $V^*$ are isomorphic this clearly isn't true. Is it true that two groups which are canonical isomorphic can be considered the same?

Comment: In groups there is nothing like choosing a basis. So, there is no question of canonical isomorphism there. I do not understand your statement **Given that $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic this clearly isn't true**

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh ok thanks for your help, so I need to treat groups and vector spaces as different entities and need to be careful about the distinction. Is the definition of an isomorphism (i.e. as I have given in one of my previous comments) the same for a group and a vector space?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Yes it is correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual

Comment: There are two answers given and you did not reply even to one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, then we get $\dim (\Lambda^k V^*) = \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k} = \dim (\Lambda^{n-k} V)$, since the binomial coefficients are symmetric. Since both have the same dimension, that already gives us that they are isomorphic as vector spaces. If you want to construct a rather complicated (algebra-)isomorphism, I would do it like this: Now, let 
$$\iota_v : \Lambda^k V \to \Lambda^{k-1} V$$
be the interior product for a $v \in V^*$. For a $w \in \Lambda^k V$ it is defined by
$$\iota_v w(u_2, ..., u_k) := w(v, u_2, ..., u_k)$$ for all $u_2, ..., u_k \in V^*$. We define recursively $\iota_{v_1 \wedge v_2} = \iota_{v_2} \circ \iota_{v_1}$.

For a given volume form $\Omega \in \Lambda^n V$ you get an isomorphism
$$\Lambda^k V^* \to \Lambda^{n-k} V, \; v \mapsto \iota_v \Omega,$$
which of course you have yet to prove. Does that help?

(Edit: I noticed that I switched the $V$ and $V^*$ in your question, but you can do pretty much the same on the dual spaces of both.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose that $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and consider a volume form $\omega$ defined on $V$. Define $f:\Lambda^kV\rightarrow \Lambda^{n-k}V^*$ as follows: On the generator $e_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_k}$, $f(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k})$ is the $n-k$-alternated form defined on $V$ by $f(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k})(u_1,...,u_{n-k})=\omega(e_1,..,e_k,u_1,..,u_{n-k})$.